# How do I use contextForSegueWithIdentifier to include data with a push segue?

Tags: swift, inheritance, segue, watchkit

My class is `class WorkoutSelectorController: WKInterfaceController {`, and I define the function `override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String) {`, which all of my research says should be called automatically when a push segue is triggered so that I can set context information to be passed.

Except that it isn't. The push segue works, but doesn't call this method. Even more, I am getting the error message "Method does not override any method from its superclass", which seems to be telling me that WKInterfaceController does not contain contextForSegueWithIdentifier. But I looked in WKInterfaceController.h, and it's definitely there, so what am I doing wrong?

Why does it say the method does not exist? How do I include context information with a push segue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function signature is wrong. The correct signature is `func contextForSegue(withIdentifier segueIdentifier: String) -> Any?` from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619522-contextforsegue).